# What type of SSRS chart will plot individual specified points?

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008

I have a query that returns six specific values, let's call them xLow, xMed, xHigh, yLow, yMed, and yHigh.

I am supposed to add a graph to a report that plots five specific points.  First is a box with corners (xLow, yLow), (xLow, yHigh), (xHigh, yLow), and (xHigh, yHigh) showing the range of possible values; then the single point (xMed, yMed) in the middle highlighting the typical value.

There is no "series" here, and this isn't exactly a Scatter Plot either.  I just need to draw some dots (and if possible connect four of them with lines.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option is to assume there is a series for the box and the mid range but then don't print the series box.

I'd play with many variations of a line chart with series to produce the box. You may need to have four series just to do this to make it look like a box.

I'm interested now and going to play.

Answer (score 0):

I got a boost here from @glh, but as with several problems I've encountered with SSRS, I've found it far easier to solve via the query rather than the report properties.  At least 80% in this case.

Basic idea of old query (within a stored proc):

```
 SELECT xHigh, xLow, xMed, yHigh, yMed, yLow
 FROM MyTable where MyPrimaryKey = @param
```

Basic idea of new query:

```
DECLARE @Holder TABLE (
    ValueLevel varchar(4),
    xVal DECIMAL (15,3),
    yHigh DECIMAL (15,3),
    yMed DECIMAL (15,3),
    yLow DECIMAL (15,3)
)
INSERT INTO @Holder
    SELECT 'Low' AS ValueLevel, xLow as xVal, yHigh, yMed, yLow
    FROM MyTable where MyPrimaryKey = @param
-- Repeat insert for xMed and xHigh
SELECT * FROM @Holder
```

Now in the rdl, my chart is a simple line chart, with three value series corresponding to the three y-values, and one group series being xVal.

I used the ValueLevel from the temp table to place a conditional on the value fields, so I only get the corners and center, and not all nine points this query produces.  For example, my expression for the yHigh series is

```
=IIF(Fields!ValueLevel.Value <> "EXP", Fields!yHigh.Value, nothing)
```

The only thing missing is the vertical connectors on the sides of the box.